# Tomcat deployment in jenkins pipeline error

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, tomcat, devops, pipeline

**Error message:**
cp /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myporject/target/petclinic.war /opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.80/webapps/
cp: cannot stat '/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.80/webapps/petclinic.war': Permission denied

- I have created a pipeline in jenkins, where built is completed and war file is available.
- I'm trying to deploy the war file in tomcat server but I'm getting permission denied error.
- tomcat is up and running.
- I'm using sudo permission to run this task.

All I want to do is to deploy my war file in tomcat

```
`stage('Copy WAR to Tomcat') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh "cp  /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myporject/target/petclinic.war /opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.80/webapps/ "
                }
            }
        }`
```

I'm getting permission denied error message in this stage of the pipeline

I have also tried this below steps, still I'm getting this error.

> chown -R jenkins /var/lib/jenkins/workspace

when I manually use this command (cp) its working but not working on my pipeline

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming permission is denied for the copy destination, not for the file you intend to copy. You will have to give permissions for `/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.80/webapps/` to your Jenkins user. The reason why it works when you do it manually (such as from the host machine terminal) is likely because then you use your own user (not Jenkins user), who has permissions to the opt directory.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm trying with sudo user for jenkins (/opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.80/webapps/) . I hope sudo user will have all the permissions.

I don't have a jenkins user in my server, Can you please help me with the steps to create jenkins user and fix this permission error?

Comment: Generally, installing Jenkins on a Linux machine also creates a Jenkins user which is then used to run anything on Jenkins. Check the contents of `/etc/passwd` to verify that a Jenkins user doesn't exist there.